# Python 2: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, list, split

I have a small problem with list. So i have a list called `l`:

```
l = ['Facebook;Google+;MySpace', 'Apple;Android']
```

And as you can see I have only 2 strings in my list. I want to separate my list `l` by **';'** and put my new 5 strings into a new list called `l1`.

How can I do that?

And also I have tried to do this like this:

```
l1 = l.strip().split(';')
```

But Python give me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

So if 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' or 'split', how can I split a list?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, `l` and `l1` are just about the worst variable names you can use; please don't use them in real code. :)

Comment: A list is already split into the list elements...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) is a method for strings, you are calling it on a `list`, hence the error.

```
>>> 'strip' in dir(str)
True
>>> 'strip' in dir(list)
False
```

To do what you want, just do

```
>>> l = ['Facebook;Google+;MySpace', 'Apple;Android']
>>> l1 = [elem.strip().split(';') for elem in l]
>>> print l1
[['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace'], ['Apple', 'Android']]
```

Since, you want the elements to be in a single list (and not a list of lists), you have two options.

1. Create an empty list and append elements to it.
2. Flatten the list.

To do the first, follow the code:

```
>>> l1 = []
>>> for elem in l:
        l1.extend(elem.strip().split(';'))  
>>> l1
['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Android']
```

To do the second, use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
>>> l1 = [elem.strip().split(';') for elem in l]
>>> print l1
[['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace'], ['Apple', 'Android']]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*l1))
['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Android']
```

Comment: yes, but i need the list l1 look like this:
   l1 = ['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Android']

Comment: How do you need your output to be? A list of lists is good enough, I think.

Comment: @MishaVayvala : I edited the answer. This should be what you want now.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is -

```
strtemp = ";".join(l)
```

The first line adds a `;` to the end of `MySpace` so that while splitting, it does not give out `MySpaceApple`
This will join l into one string and then you can just-

```
l1 = strtemp.split(";")
```

This works because strtemp is a string which has .split()

Comment: Something is wrong with your code.  I ran it and only got back 4 of the 5 items I should have.  'Apple' is missing for some reason.

Comment: Wait, let me check it. I'll get back.

Comment: Oh, thats becuase there no ';' after MySpace. Let me correct code.

Comment: wouldn't it be better if you do `";".join(l)` ?

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you want:

```
[x for y in l for x in y.split(";")]
```

output:

```
['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Android']
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps :)

```
>>> x = [i.split(";") for i in l]
>>> x
[['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace'], ['Apple', 'Android']]
>>> z = [j for i in x for j in i]
>>> z
['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Android']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent splitting way! x = [i.split(";") for i in l] has split the list, but what is the use for z = [j for i in x for j in i]? What is the difference between x and z?

Answer (score 2):

You can first concatenate the strings in the list with the separator ';' using the function `join` and then use the `split` function in order create the list:

```
l = ['Facebook;Google+;MySpace', 'Apple;Android']

l1 = ";".join(l).split(";")  

print l1 #printing
```

outputs

> ['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Android']

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I have tried right now is:
(Make sure do it in general way using for, while with index)

```
>>> l=['Facebook;Google+;MySpace', 'Apple;Android']
>>> new1 = l[0].split(';')
>>> new1
['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace']
>>> new2= l[1].split(';')`enter code here`
>>> new2
['Apple', 'Android']
>>> totalnew = new1 + new2
>>> totalnew
['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Android']
```

Answer (score 0):

You split the string entry of the list.  l[0].strip()

Answer (score 0):

Split the strings and then use [chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to combine them into a single list

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = ['Facebook;Google+;MySpace', 'Apple;Android']
>>> l1 = [ x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable( x.split(';') for x in l ) ]
>>> l1
['Facebook', 'Google+', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Android']
```