# print password.strip(",") AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: list, python-2.7, strip

I am fairly new to python. I am working on a random password generator. I was able to get my program to generate a 
random password. However it has commas (`,`) in it. I would like to strip the commas out.

It looks like I am getting an error with the strip command. The program below produces the output:

> `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'`

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import random
import string

def letter_num():
letter = random.choice(string.letters)
number = random.randint(0,9)
letter_number = [letter, number]
random_letnum = random.choice(letter_number)
return random_letnum

#print letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num,letter_num(),letter_num()

password = [letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num(),letter_num()]
print password.strip(",")
```

Comment: `print "".join(password)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 2: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751322/python-2-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-strip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in your code password is a list and you cannot use strip on list.

Try the below code

```
 #! /usr/bin/python

import random
import string

def letter_num():
    letter = random.choice(string.letters)
    number = random.randint(0,9)
    letter_number = [letter, number]
    random_letnum = random.choice(letter_number)
    return random_letnum

password = ""
for a in xrange(10):
    password += str(letter_num())

print password.strip(",")
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly. I now remember that there is a difference between a string and a list. At the risk of sounding like a moron, can you explain your block of code? I'm confused with the variable 'a'. It seems like there is no use for it. I am also confused with the "password += str(letter_num())". I'm accustom to seeing  something like "password += 1" to handle incrementation.

Comment: There is no use for 'a'; it is used to complete the syntax of the for-in loop. xrange generates the range of numbers from 0 to 10. In python += can do string concat. In python we need to do things the pythonic way. I am also new to python, so this may not be the most optimised code.

Comment: Arun, Your code is fine for me. Works great. Its funny because I woke up this morning and reread the code. I actually understood it exactly as you explained it. Thank you for your help!!!