# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

For the past 3 hours I'm trying to send an email with a CSV file attachment to a list of emails fetched from the database, but I'm getting an error which I am not really sure why is it occurring. 
I double checked my code for mistakes if there was any unicode getting passed etc, to avoid that I converted the fetched data into str but no use.

*If I run the script independently it executes and sends the email with the attachment without a problem but in Django it's giving an error.*

The emails list is made for checking whether if the error was database related but it's not. It shows up for the Pre-defined emails list as well.

I got the snippet from 
**[Here](https://www.djangospin.com/python-sending-a-mail-with-smtp-and-email-modules/)**

There is a [Reference to such an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751322/python-2-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-strip)  but I don't think it offers me anything good.

**ERROR**

Performing system checks...

> Unhandled exception in thread started by  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 228, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 124, in inner_run
>       self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 359, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 346, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
>   line 81, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 16, in check_url_config
>       return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 26, in check_resolver
>       return check_method()   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 256, in check
>       for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 35, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 407, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
>   "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 35, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 400, in urlconf_module
>       return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "C:\Users\Bitswits 3\Desktop\LCRProject\LeastCostRouting\LeastCostRouting\urls.py", line
>   12, in 
>       url('', include('LCR.urls')),   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls__init__.py",
>   line 50, in include
>       urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "C:\Users\Bitswits 3\Desktop\LCRProject\LeastCostRouting\LCR\urls.py", line 25, in
>   
>       url(r'^(?i)someemail/$', views.lcr_send_email(), name='EE-Page'),   File "C:\Users\Bitswits
>   3\Desktop\LCRProject\LeastCostRouting\LCR\views.py", line 422, in
>   lcr_send_email
>       server.sendmail(from_address, email_list, msg.as_string())   File "c:\python27\Lib\email\message.py", line 137, in as_string
>       g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)   File "c:\python27\Lib\email\generator.py", line 83, in flatten
>       self._write(msg)   File "c:\python27\Lib\email\generator.py", line 115, in _write
>       self._write_headers(msg)   File "c:\python27\Lib\email\generator.py", line 164, in _write_headers
>       v, maxlinelen=self._maxheaderlen, header_name=h).encode()   File "c:\python27\Lib\email\header.py", line 410, in encode
>       value = self._encode_chunks(newchunks, maxlinelen)   File "c:\python27\Lib\email\header.py", line 370, in _encode_chunks
>       _max_append(chunks, s, maxlinelen, extra)   File "c:\python27\Lib\email\quoprimime.py", line 97, in _max_append
>       L.append(s.lstrip()) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

CODE

```py
def lcr_send_email():


    template = "LCR\LCR_Email.html"

    email_list = []
    vendor_list = []

    email_data = RecipientEmails.objects.values_list(
        'recipient_email', flat=True)

    for i in email_data:
        email_list.append(str(i))


    for z in email_list:
        print type(z)

    vendor_name = Vendor.objects.values_list('ven_name', flat=True)
    for i in vendor_name:
        vendor_list.append(str(i))

    emails =[
'foo@example.com',
'bar@example.com',
...
]

    subject = vendor_list
    password = settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
    email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER  # email from
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp_port = 587
    from_address = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    from_password = settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
    mail_body = "This is an automated respose"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['To'] = email_list

    msg.attach(MIMEText(mail_body))

    file = "MyCsv.csv"
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="{0}"'.format(os.path.basename(file)))
    msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(from_address, from_password)
    server.sendmail(from_address, email_list, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Comment: which version of django?

Comment: Django  = 1.11.17
Python = 2.7

Comment: There's a lot of weirdness going on here. Why are you not using either Django's provided mail functions, or even the smtplib `send_email` message, rather than the really low-level `sendmail`? But to solve your problem we probably need to see the EMAI_HOST_USER value.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's DjangoEmail@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Python makes sending email relatively easy via the smtplib module, Django provides a couple of light wrappers over it. These wrappers are provided to make sending email extra quick, to make it easy to test email sending during development, and to provide support for platforms that can’t use SMTP.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for but it works.
Can you explain as to why isn't my code running.

Comment: @Djang000 I think that is not important. We upgraded Django to 2.2 and Python to 3.7 for production in our company. So I suggest you to try them.