# My discord bot is not working and I don't know why. 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'?? I don't understand

Tags: python, discord, bots

Ok. So my problem is, that I'm trying to code a discord bot and i've been trying to run it, but it always fails. In short the bot will give the user who reacted to a message in a certain channel a certain role named "mietzekatze" and that's it. The code is from "import discord... client.run(TOKEN)" and the error message is everything followed by the code.

```
TOKEN = ['XXXXX']
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel('828667703966433331')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == ":white_check_mark:":
      Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="mietzekatze")
      await client.add_roles(user, Role)
client.run(TOKEN)

File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\XXX\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\XXX\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\XXX\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\XXX\Documents\servers\server bot dc\bot.py", line 12, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 2: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751322/python-2-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-strip)

Comment: Never mind. I just had to put TOKEN in () not [].